# Best way to make solid wireframe material with Away3d?

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d, stage3d

Can't find any good example of solid wireframe material in Away3d. Maybe I am using wrong tool?

Answer (score 0):

There is a set of Wireframe primitives, like WireframeSphere and WireframeCube. Just define them and add to the scene:

```
var primitive = new WireframeCube(400,800,400,0xFFFFFF,1);
primitive.x = 1000;
scene.addChild(primitive);
```

But I believe you want to apply wireframe to non primitive object. In that case - I'm also looking for the answer...

**EDIT:**

I have found some workaround called WireframeMapGenerator. It's not true wire frame material but at least it works:
http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/779/#2597